# Find columns that match in two tables

Tags: sql-server, pattern-matching

I need to query two tables of companies in the first table are the full names of companies, and the second table are also the names but are incomplete. The idea is to find the fields that are similar. I put pictures of the reference and SQL code I'm using.

[image]

The result I want is like this

[image]

The closest way I found to do so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    RTRIM(a.NombreEmpresaBD_A) as NombreReal, 
    b.EmpresaDB_B as NombreIncompleto 
FROM EmpresaDB_A a, EmpresaDB_B b 
WHERE a.NombreEmpresaBD_A LIKE 'VoIP%' AND b.EmpresaDB_B LIKE 'VoIP%'
```

The problem with the above code is that it only returns the record specified in the WHERE and if I put this LIKE '%' it returns the Cartesian product of two tables. The RDBMS is Microsoft SQL Server. I would greatly appreciate if you help me with any proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the short name plus appended '%' as argument in the LIKE expression:

#### Edit with info that we deal with SQL Server:

```
SELECT a.NombreEmpresaBD_A as NombreReal
      ,b.NombreEmpresaBD_B as NombreIncompleto 
FROM   EmpresaDB_A a, EmpresaDB_B b
WHERE  a.NombreEmpresaBD_A LIKE (b.NombreEmpresaBD_B + '%');
```

According to your screenshot you had the **column name wrong**!
String concatenation in T-SQL with `+` operator.
Above query finds a case where

```
'Computex S.A' LIKE 'Computex%'
```

but **not**:

```
'Voip Service Mexico' LIKE 'VoipService%'
```

For that you would have to strip blanks first or use more powerful pattern matching functions.
I have created a [demo for you on data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1946/demo-for-aldonas).
Look up [pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx) or the [LIKE operator in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx).

Comment: It is a Microsoft SQL Server. Apply the logic of the solution you suggest, without encambio got no results.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution proposed is the most successful. At the end send the results to another table with INSERT INTO and everything worked fine. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a foreign key between the tables linking the data.  Then you can just search for the one table and join the second to get the other results.